# navbar-right does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Self-explanatory. Why does navbar-right not close out the two nav bar elements to the right? I have added the proper code so I am confused as to why it does not work.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-expanded" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-="data-" toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-up" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-in" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: #navbarRespons]

Comment: _"I have added the proper code"_ mmmm, nope. See [mcve]

Comment: what is not proper about this

Comment: that isn't html for starters. please compile the pug code so we don't have to. and the code you included doesn't replicate the screenshot. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwNJVQ

Comment: Converted to html

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your collapse `button` and you have a bunch of errors in the attributes of that tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-expanded" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">menu</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-up" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-in" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @konyv12 look at the difference in the tag in my answer and yours. You didn't close the tag, so it was wrapping the whole nav. the class needs to be `.navbar-toggle` not `.navbar-toggler` and `data-="data-" toggle="collapse"` is wrong, needs to be `data-toggle="collapse"`

Comment: I fixed those, still the same.

Comment: never mind, I had to use ml-auto and mr-auto. its a template i bought

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? add `navbar-right` to the parent of that two `<ul>` element and remove them from `<ul>`:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarResponsive">`

```css
nav {
  margin-top: 100px; /* ignore this, just to show example at stackoverflow*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-expanded" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">My Menu</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-up" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="sign-in" style="background-color:blue; border-radius:5px">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```